# Heroku error : no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am using Mysql on my local mashine. I am having a problem when I tries to push the database. 
I have installed taps.

```
   Home@PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
    $ heroku db:push
    Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
    On most systems this will be:

    sudo gem install taps
```

Updated I get the following error now:

```
Ruby.exe system error
The program could not be started because sqlite3.dll is missing on the computer.
```

My database yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
# gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
# gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'

development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: konkurranceportalen
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqld.sock
  host: 127.0.0.1

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: rails_t
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqld.sock
  host: 127.0.0.1

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: rails_p
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqld.sock
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did download sqlite.dll here http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
and did paste it in ruby/bin and myapp/tmp/sockets
Then I could run heroku db:push

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to my Gemfile within the 'development' group fixed it for me.

Comment: Tænkte på om du ved hvor det er muligt at få arbejde deltid, som ROR udvikler? :)

Comment: Du skulle prøve at send en shout på Copenhagen.rb mailing list -> http://copenhagenrb.dk/ der er altid en masse firmaer som søger efter rails udvikler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Taps gem first. It should work automagically after that.

See if your database.yml file is correctly configured.

Or just use

```
$ heroku db:push mysql://root:mypass@localhost/mydb
```

Fill in the required details in the above command.

Comment: can you post your database.yml file

Comment: I have posted my database yml

Comment: I get the ruby system error I have posted when heroku db:push  mysql://root:mypass@localhost/mydb